# rails 3.1 - simple_captcha doesn't generate image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to use simple_captcha on my application but it doesn't seem to produce an image on my dev machine. 1.8.7, rails 3.1 here. If I attempt to visit the image URL i get an error "cannot generate tempfile `'".

Any ideas? I 'd like some help since I don't want to use recaptcha. thanks!

Comment: most likely a permission problem,  what is the dev machine?   You should also just fire up the RMagick command line,  or re-run the RMagick install tests,  maybe that will help you narrow it down.  Sorry I can't be more help, it was a long time ago when I installed simple_captcha and RMagic

Comment: I like recaptcha since reCAPTCHA is a free CAPTCHA service that helps to digitize books, newspapers and old time radio shows (via) http://www.google.com/recaptcha/learnmore

Comment: See some options of captcha here - https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_captcha You might not want to use and old version of a ruby gem since it would cause problems in the long run.

Comment: I have Rmagick installed. require 'RMagick' returns true. Imagemagick is also installed and i pass the convert label test. I don't want to use recaptcha because i feel i can't customize it's looks enough. I use Ubuntu on my dev machine

Answer (score 2):

The error you get can be fixed by setting an explicit tmp_path by adding an initializer to config/initializers/:

```
SimpleCaptcha.setup do |captcha_config|
  captcha_config.tmp_path = Rails.root + 'tmp'
end
```